# Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $localstorageProvider <- $localstorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Was using ionic, in my app.js I do

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers','ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $localStorage , $cordovaPush) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    console.log($localStorage);
  })
})
```

But I got error of `Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $localstorageProvider <- $localstorage`

Any thought? so strange..

Comment: You're injecting $local**S**torage but the error message says $local**s**torage. You're sure about the case?

Comment: Modified my answer. Rectified a simple mistake. It should work now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
$localstorage
```

to

```
$window.localStorage //S is capitalized
```

And inject the `$window` dependancy in your run function.

Answer (score 10):

you are possibly missing a dependency! have a look at e.g. https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage.

include it into your project and require the ngStorage-module like so:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ngStorage', 'ionic', 'starter.controllers','ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $localStorage , $cordovaPush) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    console.log($localStorage); // edit: capital S
  })
})
```

Comment: This solved my issue. I was missing 'ngStorage' in my module.

Answer (score 0):

```
    angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers','ngCordova','ngStorage'])

    .run(function($ionicPlatform, $localStorageProvider , $cordovaPush) {  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
console.log($localStorageProvider);
 })
})
```

to get a previously saved key from localstorage use as follows

```
    $localStorageProvider.get('YOUR_KEY');
```

see https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage